# Storing array in sqlite/pg databases with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying store an array of strings in an heroku PG database.

I've tried marshal dumping to a string which works in sqlite. However with PG if the array is too large it doesn't save the entire dumped string and fails to load the array when trying to access it. When trying to access the array, I get error `marshal data too short'

migration

```
add_column :orders, :photo_urls, :text, :limit => nil
```

Alternatively, I tried to use `serialize :photo_urls` int the model. Again, this works in sqlite, but in production PG, I get the error `array value must start with "{" or dimension information`

Tried both migrations with different default settings:

```
add_column :orders, :photo_urls, :text, array: true, default: []
add_column :orders, :photo_urls, :text, array: true, default: '{}'
```

Is there a different way to store an array in both sqlite and PG?

Answer (score 0):

I had to serialize the array ONLY for sqlite in my development environment.

```
serialize :photo_urls if Rails.env.development?
```

migration

```
add_column :orders, :photo_urls, :text, array: true, default: []
```

Comment: But you won't be able to query the columns the same way. If you're doing this to develop on SQLite and deploy on PostgreSQL then you're making a big mistake.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Outside of calling `order.photo_urls`, I won't be using any queries involving the array

Comment: PostgreSQL has [lots of operators and functions for working with arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html), you can't do any of that with a serialized column; if you don't need to query inside the array then it won't matter. Differences in how types work, string lengths are handled, GROUP BY works, ... between the two databases will cause problems sooner or later.

Comment: It's only being serialized in my dev environment, which uses sqlite. But I understand what your saying that it can introduce unexpected complications. Do you have a suggestion for an alternative implementation?

Comment: Install PostgreSQL in your development environment. Don't expect ActiveRecord to give you much help with portability.